# How can I import a custom package in IntelliJ IDEA (Java)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, package, classpath

There is such term like `CLASSPATH` which is using that JVM could find custom classes or `jar` files to import them to another packages (**Am I right?**). So, I created a few custom classes and placed them into package `net.ederika`, then I created another project with `net.bartikan` package name. My main idea is to import classes from `net.ederika` package to the second project. I specified `CLASSPATH` environment variable [CLASSPATH EV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GyR8.png) and added to `C:/DOC/JavaT net/edeirika/` files with extension `.class`. I got this: [Error with package importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfXXI.png)
I used IntelliJ IDEA for this. What's wrong with my actions? **Bruce Eckel** (*"Thinking in Java" book*) wrote that we specify `CLASSPATH`, add there folders with out `.class` files and JVM locates it. I'm really frustrated and confused with this topic and can't merely go on reading that book. [From *"Thinking in Java"*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71NYv.png) There is no really much info about it on the Internet, thus I ask here. [files in `CLASSPATH` specified folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZQhR.png)

Comment: "*There is no really much info about it on the Internet*" you're just not looking in the right places

Comment: Note, that _importing_ is a compile-time feature for the source code. This has nothing to do with the _classpath_, which is a run-time feature.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose But why Bruce Eckel and Cay Horstman connected importing custom packages and `CLASSPATH`? If it's not for importing, then what is? How do people do it, at usual (_importing_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDEA: File > Project Stucture > Libraries > `+` > Java > Select Library Files > OK > Apply > OK

#### First, find Preject Structure in a file in the toolbar

[image: Step one]

#### Then click the plus sign, which means to add an external Project Library of your choice, where I am demonstrating the Java Library

[image: Step two]

#### Then find the Java Library file path and click OK

[image: Step three]

#### Finally, click Apply and ok

[image: Step four]

Comment: you should add some note on what you're doing